# Creating an STA thread when using Reactive Extensions (Rx) schedulers

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I need an STA thread to use with `Observable.Create`, (the scheduler is defined using the `SubScribeOn` method). My question is what is the best way to create an STA thread in Rx.

Currently I have the following working with the NewThreadScheduler but I could use the EventLoopScheduler instead.

**Which is better suited for creating an STA thread?**

```
Func<ThreadStart, Thread> func = x =>
{
  var thread = new Thread(x) { IsBackground = true };
  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

  return thread;
};

return new NewThreadScheduler(func);
```

.Net version: 4.0 (WPF)

Rx version: 2.0.21103.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EventLoopScheduler` and `NewThreadScheduler` are both acceptable, depending upon your needs.  The difference is essentially this:

1. `EventLoopScheduler` employs single-threaded asynchrony; i.e., a dedicated background thread.  If you create an instance of this scheduler and pass it around to many operators, then all actions scheduled by those operators (including, but not limited to, calls to `OnNext`) are enqueued and serialized onto a single thread.
2. `NewThreadScheduler` employs concurrency.  As an optimization, overlapping notifications will appear on the same thread, though you should not rely on this.

Comment: Dave uses bigger and fancier words than me. :) +1

Comment: Lol.  I'm pretending to know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

They achieve different goals:

- `NewThreadScheduler` will dispatch events to subscribers as soon as possible by using multiple threads (concurrency). Threads will be reused for efficiency. Pick this because you want subscribers to get their events asap without other subscribers holding things up.
- `EventLoopScheduler` will dispatch events to subscribers on the same thread. Pick this one because you want everything run on the one thread.